# How to share the scope within module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Inside handler.js and I have exported 2 functions. One for `initialize()` and other `handle()`. Initialize function use to load handler dynamic based on the application settings. And I have shared variable `var handler` outside the module.exports function.

`handler = new Handler(app);` new instance created assign to shared variable `var handler`. And then inside `handle()` function shared variable `var handler`. used

Dynamically  `require()` a file in web request time is not good idea. So  `initialize()` method created and called in application start time.

Let me know suggestion to remove the shared variable 'handler'

```
var handler;

module.exports  = {

    initialize : function (app){
        var Handler = require(path.resolve(app.basedir, app.settings.handler));
        handler = new Handler(app);
    },

    handle : function handle(ctx) {

        var urlToHandle = ctx.url;

         return handler.resolveURL(ctx)
        .then(function (json) {
            ctx.layoutJSON = json;
            return ctx;
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            throw e;
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, why do you need to remove `handler`, the middleware is wrapped in an IIFE and cached by Node anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your right, but if you call the initialize just once you can do something like that:

```
var app     = require('path-to-a-file-which-return-app');
var Handler = require(path.resolve(app.basedir, app.settings.handler));
var handler = new Handler(app);

module.exports  = {

    handle : function handle(ctx) {

        var urlToHandle = ctx.url;

         return handler.resolveURL(ctx)
        .then(function (json) {
            ctx.layoutJSON = json;
            return ctx;
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            throw e;
        });

    }
};
```

Now the require will just be called once, since Node will cache it for you.